Smallest $k$ s.t. $\operatorname{rank} A^m=\operatorname{rank} A^k$ for all $m>k$.
Problem: Let $A\in \mathbb C^{n\times n}$ be a matrix. Determine the smallest number $k\in \mathbb N$ (dependent on $A$), such that $\operatorname{rank} A^m=\operatorname{rank} A^k$ for all $m>k$.
So far: My intuitive thought was to somehow decompose $A$ and use the fact that similar matrices have the same rank, but I can't see this to the end. Any tips are welcome. The most recent things we've covered are nilpotency and the Jordan normal form, if that helps.

Suppose $J$ is a Jordan block of dimension $n \times n$ with $\lambda$ on the diagonal. What does the sequence $\operatorname{rank} J^1, \operatorname{rank} J^2, \operatorname{rank} J^3, \dotsc$ look like?

Is it just identically $n$ if $\lambda \neq 0$ and identically $n-1$ if $\lambda=0$?

I agree with your assessment for $\lambda \ne 0$. If $\lambda = 0$, try working out the cases $n = 2, 3$ by hand to check if you're right. But also: don't just stop there! I have given you a hint about a case to start with - you should think about how this helps you solve the original problem.

For the $\lambda=0$ case we have $n-1, n-2, \ldots, 0, 0, \ldots$, right?

So if $A=PJP^{-1}$, where $\operatorname{diag}J=0$, then we can choose $k=n$. Else we choose $k=0$?

Yes, if $A$ is conjugate to a Jordan block that's right. But sometimes the JNF can consist of more than one block...

Right... (?), this isn't exactly helping

If $\mathbb N$ includes zero, then $k$ is the power of $x$ in the minimal polynomial $m(x)$ of $A$. That is, if $m(x)=x^rf(x)$ for some polynomial $f$ with $f(0)\ne0$, then the exponent $r$ in $m$ is the $k$ in your question. If you want a strictly positive $k$, you may take $k=\max(r,1)$.

The arguments below are unchecked, so you can consider them as an extended hint.
We shall call the required $k$ the rank stabilizer of $A$. Let $J$ be a Jordan normal form of the matrix $A$. Then there exists a matrix $P\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}$ such that $J=P^{-1}AP$. Then for any natural $m$ we have $J^m=P^{-1}A^mP$ so $\operatorname{rank} A^m=\operatorname{rank} J^m$. It follows that the rank stabilizer of $A$ is equal to the rank stabilizer of $J$. Moreover, since the matrix $J^m$ is block-diagonal, its rank equals to the sum of ranks of its block-diagonal cells. Therefore the rank stabilizer of $J$ is equal to the maximum
of the rank stabilizers of its cells. So it suffices to know the rank stabilizer of an $r\times r$ Jordan cell $J_r(\lambda)$ corresponding to a number $\lambda$, for any natural $r$ and any real $\lambda$.
If $\lambda\ne 0$ then the matrix $J_r(\lambda)^m$ is nonsingular for each natural $m$, so the rank stabilizer of $J_r(\lambda)$ equals $1$. If $\lambda=0$ then it is easy to check the matrix $J_r(\lambda)^{r-1}\ne 0=J_r(\lambda)^r$, so the rank stabilizer of $J_r(\lambda)$ equals $r$.

I think the rank stabiliser of $J_r(0)$ is $r$, right?

@IzaakvanDongen Thank for your attention and sorry for the misprint. I corrected it.
